# Storing Facebook Users City and State Separately

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am currently building a social media app that allows users to sign up via Facebook. My sign up process is working fine, but one thing I would like to do is request the users City and State and store them as separate keys in my database. This way I can allow users to search a user by city or state in my app.

I already have the FBRequestConnection method set up and pulling the users location as a whole.

Is it possible to query city and state and store them separately? If so, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your code for how you are doing this now? I assume you are using `[FBRequest requestForMe]` to get the user's FBGraphUser. FBGraphUser has a location property which is an FBGraphPlace. The FBGraphPlace has a location property which is an FBGraphLocation. FBGraphLocation has string and number properties for city, country, state, etc. What are you doing to get the location now?

Comment: Yes I am using the [FBRequestrequestForMe]. Then I grab the user location by the below code:
      if ([result objectForKey:@"location"]) {
        NSString *facebookLocation = [[result objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"name"];
        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:facebookLocation forKey:@"location"];
      }

Comment: Would there be a better way for me to extract the user location information?

Comment: Im storing the information into the Parse platform by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments you are now doing this:

```
[FBRequestrequestForMe]
```

and then:

```
if ([result objectForKey:@"location"]) {
    NSString *facebookLocation = [[result objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:facebookLocation forKey:@"location"];
}
```

The `result` is an `FBGraphUser` object and the `location` property you are accessing is an `FBGraphPlace` object:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphPlace

You are currently accessing the `name` property of the `FBGraphPlace` which is giving you an NSString representation of the place. What you want to do instead is access the `location` property which is an `FBGraphLocation`. This object has properties for the various components you want:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphLocation

(I'm not on a Mac right now, so there are probably some errors in this code) You should be able to do something like this:

```
id<FBGraphUser> fbUser = (id<FBGraphUser>)result;
id<FBGraphPlace> fbPlace = [fbUser location];
id<FBGraphLocation> fbLocation = [fbPlace location];
NSString * userCity = [fbLocation city];
NSString * userCountry = [fbLocation country];
NSString * userZip = [fbLocation zip];
//etc
```

You can then use this information however you'd like with your Parse user:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:userCity forKey:@"city"];
[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:userZip forKey:@"zip"];
```

Comment: Thats great!! Thanks a million!